# Is “all swans are white” equivalent to “if it is not white, then it is not a swan”?

Tags: logic

More formally, is "All As are Bs" equivalent to "if it is not a B, then it is not an A"?

Comment: You might find it interesting to read about the [Raven Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raven_paradox)

Comment: Don't lose your quantifier: "Everything that is not an B is also not a A".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. This is called the contrapositive of the statement.  $A \Rightarrow B$ is equivalent to the statement $\neg B \Rightarrow $$\neg A$

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) as well.

Comment: I would prefer saying "$A\implies B$ is equivalent to saying $\neg B\implies \neg A$", which is stronger.

Comment: You're right. I'll edit the post.

Comment: I see in that link I can say they are "logically equivalent". Can I also say they are "materially equivalent", that is "all swans are white if and only if, if they are not white, they are not swans"?

Comment: The statement you have in quotes is logical equivalence. Try writing it out in quantifiers to see this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's true. Let $p_A(x)$ be *"$x$ is $A$"* and $p_B(x)$ be *"$x$ is B"*. Then *"All $A$s are $B$s"* is $$\forall\, x: \; p_A(x) \rightarrow p_B(x).$$ Statement $p_A(x) \rightarrow p_B(x)$ is false in only one case: when $p_A(x)$ is true and $p_B(x)$ is false. Similary statement $\neg p_B(x) \rightarrow \neg p_A(x)$ is false only if $\neg p_B(x)$ is true and $\neg p_A(x)$ is false, i.e. when $p_A(x)$ is true and $p_B(x)$ is false i.e. only when firs statement is false. Thus these two statements are equal because they are false and true in the same time:
$$\forall\, x: \; p_A(x) \rightarrow p_B(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall\,x : \neg p_B(x) \rightarrow \neg p_A(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Or: "If it is not white and it is still a swan, then it is not true that 'All swans are white'."